# Is there a collection of old security issues with description and exercising code for the Java platform?

Tags: java, security, jvm

I'm wondering if there is an educational collection of examples on how security on the JVM was compromised in old versions.

After reading a bit of the [articles](http://weblog.ikvm.net/CommentView.aspx?guid=4527a953-90d5-4b87-bd93-90f71690142a) [on](http://weblog.ikvm.net/Default.aspx) [the](http://weblog.ikvm.net/CommentView.aspx?guid=2b341f75-480c-4154-adc8-ce5571da35c3) IKVM blog, I have the feeling that I learn more by understanding past cases of security issues instead of reading some plain "Do's and Dont's" (looks like most of the interesting articles have been pulled, what a shame).

Is there something like that available somewhere?

Maybe I have too strong expectations: I don't care about some script-kiddy stuff, but I'm looking for quality content going into the depth about

- How was the security issue discovered?
- How would code exercising look like?
- How does the flawed code look like?
- How has the bug been fixed?
- How can the absence of the bug be verified?
- What were the reasons which caused the security issue? (Pure laziness, performance concerns, wrong assumptions, ...)
- What's the lessons, as an application developer, library designer, VM engineer?

Is there something like that available on the net?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think there is very little research on JVM exploits. What do you want to do exactly?

- Break standard Java programming restrictions: easy to do, since you can access everything when running standard bytecode.
- Circumvent the Java Security Policy when executing java code (e.g. break out of the browser sandbox): This has very little to do with the JVM; it is often a combination of browser-based exploits and other exploits to be able to launch the applet and include the boot classpath of a standard JVM.
- Launch a buffer overflow attack on the OS from within the JVM.

Often, breaking out of the browser sandbox is trivial and has nothing to do with the JVM itself: http://jouko.iki.fi/adv/javaplugin.html

The best information will be available from an open-source JVM like BlackDown. Search the SVN changelog for the words 'exploit', 'bug', 'sandbox' and look at the SVN Diff's.